# Sphere fit with given radius, matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to have a matlab function for fitting a sphere  given that X=[x,y,z].

The radius is fixed/known. It should be taken as input and not estimated again. Estimation of radius causes extra error source. 
I found out two usefull links

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45356-fitting-quadratic-curves-and-surfaces/content/spherefit.m

http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34129-sphere-fit--least-squared-

I can fit a sphere by using both functions but how can I fix my radius and not to be estimated.

-------------------------------------EDITED------------------------------------------------

I tried

```
POINTS = [...
            -1.6510    0.4190    0.1580
   -1.6410    0.4390    0.1770
   -1.6620    0.4380    0.1320
   -1.6610    0.3990    0.1980
   -1.6510    0.4180    0.2090
   -1.6460    0.4470    0.2130
   -1.6450    0.4730    0.1950
   -1.6540    0.4720    0.1480
   -1.6730    0.3960    0.1530
   -1.6790    0.3850    0.1770
   -1.6450    0.4220    0.1850
   -1.6470    0.4360    0.1540
   -1.6570    0.4600    0.1370
   -1.6770    0.4160    0.1300
   -1.6630    0.4280    0.2340
   -1.6690    0.4070    0.2250
   -1.6550    0.4540    0.2270
   -1.6430    0.4690    0.1740
   -1.6410    0.4400    0.1930
   -1.6560    0.4030    0.1880
   -1.6600    0.3990    0.1720
   -1.6400    0.4530    0.1810];

Radius_act= 0.0725;
Center_act = [-1.712637 0.448658 0.183808 ];

XYZ = bsxfun(@plus,Radius_act*POINTS, Center_act);
```

f = @(C) sum((sum(bsxfun(@minus,XYZ,C).^2,2)-Radius_act^2).^2);

```
estimateCenter = fminsearch(f, [0,0,0])


[Center_LSE,Radius_LSE] = sphereFit(M)
```

BUT  WHY it is different????????????

```
estimateCenter =   -1.7640    0.4576    0.1906


Center_LSE =   -1.7122    0.4485    0.1838


Radius_LSE =    0.0725
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. The radius is the second output of the second script you've found on matlal central. You already have it.

Comment: @  Bentoy1 The radius is fixed/known. It should be taken as input and not estimated again. Estimation of radius causes extra error source

Comment: Ah ok, I understand your trouble!

Comment: So, you want to fit an sphere of known radius to some data. In practical terms, what you want to do is just find the center of an sphere with a given radius that fits best to your data.  Am I understanding it right?

Comment: `Sphere Fit` from the file-exchange tells us in it's documentation, that it is minimizing `Sum((x-xc)^2+(y-yc)^2+(z-zc)^2-r^2)^2`, so your best bet is to minimize this function using a fixed `r` and varying `xc`, `yc`, `zc`.

Comment: @Ander Bigur Yes. you are right.

Answer (score 1):

As a first try you could minimize the same objection function that *Sphere Fit* from the FileExchange is using: `Sum((x-xc)^2+(y-yc)^2+(z-zc)^2-r^2)^2`. [That's what it states in the documentation at least... If this is the correct choice, I'm not sure, but we'll trust this source for now.]

Let's simply use the automagic function `fminsearch` from the minimization toolbox:

```
f = @(C) sum((sum(bsxfun(@minus,XYZ,C).^2,2)-r^2).^2);
estimateCenter = fminsearch(f, [0,0,0]);
```

For the example data:

```
r = 3;
realCenter = [10,20,40];
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(10);
XYZ = bsxfun(@plus,r*[X(:),Y(:),Z(:)], realCenter);
```

This will get us:

```
estimateCenter =
   10.0000   19.9999   40.0000
```

If you want better approximations, you can set the error tolerance of your dreams using `fminsearch(..., optimset('TolX',1e-4))`.

Comment: wow....let me try it.Thanx anyhow.

Comment: @ please see edited one.

Comment: @Shah: There is no "edited one".

Comment: @Shah: Looks good to me. What's the problem?

Comment: @ knedlsepp see please.........

Comment: estimateCenter should be close to actual one.

Comment: I had a look already. What do you expect?

Comment: This IS close!! If you want lower tolerance enter `doc fminsearch` and look for *Termination tolerance*.

Comment: I was expecting that estimateCenter and Center_LSE should deliver same answer with the advantage that estimateCenter (your suggestion) has fixed radius.

Comment: Also: You did change the name of the variable `r`, but not in the function `f`!!!

Comment: This was copy paste mistake.f = @(C) sum((sum(bsxfun(@minus,XYZ,C).^2,2)-Radius_act^2).^2);